# How to Average an aggregate column

Tags: sql

How do I write a query that averages an aggregate (another average)?

Here's what I have so far.

```
SELECT AVG(stars)
FROM Rating
WHERE mID IN
    (SELECT mID
    FROM Movie
    WHERE year > 1980)
GROUP BY mID
```

I want to average the output of that query.

The underlying data is:

```
(Stars,mID)

(2,104)
(3,104)
(3,107)
(5,107)
(4,108)
(2,108)
(4,108)
```

I can get averages grouped by mID with the above query.

```
[AVG(stars),mID]

(2.50,104)
(4.00,107)
(3.33,108)
```

Now I want to take the avg of (2.5 + 4.0 + 3.33)

Expected answer = 3.2767

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, just remove the group by statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an overall average of all the ratings as:

```
SELECT AVG(stars)
FROM Rating
WHERE mID IN (SELECT mID FROM Movie WHERE year > 1980);
```

But you probably want each movie to have the same weight.  For that us a subquery:

```
SELECT AVG(avg_stars)
FROM (SELECT AVG(stars) as avg_stars
      FROM Rating
      WHERE mID IN (SELECT mID FROM Movie WHERE year > 1980);
      GROUP BY mID
     ) r;
```

Comment: That second answer with the subquery was what I was looking for Gordon. Thanks!

Comment: One part I don't understand - What does the ') r; ' in the last line do? I assume it's aliasing the rating table but I don't understand it's function.

Comment: @CarsonCunningham . . . It is aliasing the subquery.  Some databases require aliases on subqueries in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the first resul as a FROM( subquery ) for the main avg

```
select avg(my_avg)
from  (
  SELECT AVG(stars) my_avg 
  FROM Rating r 
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT mID
      FROM Movie
      WHERE year > 1980 
  ) t on t.mID  = r.mID
  GROUP BY mID
) t2
```